# How to record tests on robotium for Android test?

Tags: android, robotium, monkeytalk, robotium-recorder

I am using MonkeyTalk for Android app test. I have some basic idea about robotium. But unfortunately I don't know how to record and play back using Robotium. Is there any way? If yes how?

Answer (score 2):

Now, Robotium have recording facility with eclipse. You need to install eclipse plugin for this. (http://recorder.robotium.com/updates)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Robotium but didnt find a direct way to record test execution. I use MyMobiler application to record test execution.

If you are running the test cases on a device then you can use MyMobiler application.

http://www.mymobiler.com/

What this application does is it shows you the display of device on the PC. You also have an option within MyMobiler application to record.

Comment: Is it free? I mean is it open soure?

Comment: Yes. you'll get all info on their site.

Comment: I have downloaded "MyMobiler_0.9.8.1.exe" and installed. I have set up Android environment within eclipse. I ran my app on Nexus S device. MyMobiler is showing the status as "USB Connected". Now, How & where can I record the tests?

Comment: First follow the steps at http://www.mymobiler.com/android-setup-start.htm . Once you do that you'll get the android device display on the PC. On PC in MyMobiler screen, Click on Edit--> Video Record Start...

Comment: The above URL is not working. The correct one is http://www.mymobiler.com/android-setup-start.html

Answer (score 0):

**Install Robotium Recorder for Eclipse:**

1. Start Eclipse and go to: Help -> Install New Software...
2. Enter "http://recorder.robotium.com/updates" in the "Work with" field
3. Press Enter and wait for Robotium to get visible. Check Robotium Recorder and uncheck "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" before clicking "Next"
4. Click Next button from the Install Details screen and follow the eclipse guideline

**Start Robotium Recorder:**

Robotium Recorder can be started from: Eclipse > File > New > Other. From "New" window select "New Robotium Test" and click "Next".

For details you can visit:  [Robotium Recorder Install and Start](http://robotium.com/pages/installation)